# Application of RARP protocol

Tags: networking, arp

I know the `RARP protocol` is used for **mapping physical address to logical address** and its some practical applications. Now I have studied `RARP(reverse ARP) protocol` but cannot find its **practical applications**. Can anyone give some **scenerios and practical applications of RARP protocol**.

Comment: RARP is used by a host to find it own IP address, but we now use DHCP for that. RARP is dead.

Answer (score 4):

[RARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Address_Resolution_Protocol) is now an obsolete protocol that was used to allow a host to determine it's IP address based on the host's MAC address.  The protocol was rendered obsolete by more modern techniques and protocols such as [BOOTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_Protocol) and [DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol).

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that RARP is obsolete, because it's extremely handy in determining an unknown IP address of a device. If someone sets a static IP on a device, then years later it is forgotten, moved to a different network, found sitting on a shelf and someone wants to use it, you could RARP the MAC address printed on the device to retrieve its IP.